# Wordpress comment_form() problems

Tags: wordpress, forms, blogs, contacts

I have a comments.php file with this code

```
$fields =  array(
  'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name' ) .    '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
  '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
  'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) .
  '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',
  'url'    => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Website' ) . '</label>' .
  '<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></p>',
);

$comments_args = array(
  'fields' =>  $fields
);

comment_form($comments_args);
```

I then include it with this:

```
get_template_part('comments');
```

But the comment form that shows is this:

[image]

Not at all what I want, where is my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logged in as the admin – try logging out and see what happens.